# For iOS Apps, updating with new language treated as new app in that country?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Have anyone had the experience of updating an app with a new language support and know if Apple treats it as a new app for that Country?  Say you update with chinese support, would it be shown as a New app? Say in the 'Whats New'.

If not, maybe there is an advantage in releasing an app with as many language as possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple shows apps in "New and Noteworthy" if they have a recent release or update date.

The local iTunes team for your country might feature your app if you updated it to include the local language.

Generally the advantage of localiztion can only be realized if the app has been selling well before. Just adding localization will not save an app that nobody cares about beforehand.